# Prove the norm property of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ is a random variable. Then prove this inequality.
$$
\|X\|_{L^2} \leq \|X\|_{L^1}^{\frac{1}{4}}\|X\|_{L^3}^{\frac{3}{4}}
$$

I think maybe using Caushy-Schwarz is effective but was stucked on this proposition.
I'll give a great appropriciate you!

Answer (score 1):

Write
$X^2=\lvert X\rvert^{1/2}\lvert X\rvert^{3/2}$ and apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in order to bound $\mathbb E\left[X^2\right]$. Then rearrange everything in terms of norms.